Modifying advanced search query based on custom fields
I have got a multi-select autocomplete-select custom field that I am trying to use with advanced search. It works however I would like to optimize/make some adjustments to fit my needs better:

is there a way to modify to query builder to select records that not only equal to but also begin with my custom field values (in sql terms from ... field = 'value' ... to ... field like 'value%' ...).
I have noticed that multiple values are separated by ascii 1 char in the database but have not found a query that does the split at the database level. Is my observation right? Am I safe to assume this happens at the application level? Is there a way to override this code at the extension level?

when I specify more than one value I see that the query uses AND operator - how do I go about changing it to OR



You can use search-kit and do various conditioning your self.
